# Can I apply the gradient theorem for a field with not simply connected domain?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, line-integrals, greens-theorem

Let $ \pmb G $ be a vector field with domain $ U \subseteq \mathbb{R^2}. $

If $ U $ is not simply connected, but there exists a function $ f $
such that $ \pmb G = \pmb \nabla f \; \; \forall \; (x,y) \in U$, are we permitted to apply the gradient theorem (for paths that pass only through points which belong to $U$) ?

For example,
$ \pmb G(x,y) = \Biggl( \cfrac{\partial}{\partial x} 
\biggl( \cfrac{x}{x^2+y^2} \biggr) ,
\cfrac{\partial}{\partial y} \biggl( \cfrac{x}{x^2+y^2} \biggr) \Biggr) \; , \;
(x,y) \neq \pmb 0.
$

We can see that
$ U = \mathbb{R^2} \setminus \{\pmb 0\} $
is not simply connected, however it is true that
$ \pmb G = \pmb \nabla f \; \; \forall \; (x,y) \neq \pmb 0 $
, where
$ f(x,y)= \cfrac{x}{x^2+y^2}  \; , \; (x,y) \neq \pmb 0 $.

So, can we use the gradient theorem in order to calculate line integrals
$ \oint_c \pmb G \: d \pmb s $
for paths that do not pass through $ \pmb 0 $, ignoring the fact that the domain is not simply connected ?

Comment: No, there are nontrivial line integrals over loops in this domain and thus you may not apply the theorem.

Comment: @rubikscube09 : Your answer applies to my specific example or generally? Because, for this specific vector field, it is true that $ \pmb G = \pmb \nabla f $ , and $ \pmb G $ and $ f $ have the same domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the [gradient theorem, also known as the fundamental theorem of calculus for line integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_theorem), is true on any open domain, whether or not it is simply connected.

What the theorem says is

> For any open set $U \subset \mathbb R^n$, any smooth function $f : U \to \mathbb R$ with gradient vector field $\pmb G = \pmb\nabla f$, and any $p,q \in U$, no matter what path $c : [0,1] \to U$ one chooses with $c(0)=p$ and $c(1)=q$ we have
>   $$\int_c \pmb G = \int_c \pmb \nabla f = f(c(1))-f(c(0)) = f(q)-f(p)
> $$

And so yes, the path integrals of $\pmb G$ are indeed independent of the choice of $c$.

What you might be confusing this with is the theorem which characterizes conservative vector fields, and which *does* need simple connectivity in its hypotheses:

> If $\pmb G$ is a vector field on a simply connected domain $U$, then $\pmb G$ is a gradient vector field (i.e. $\pmb G$ is conservative) if and only if $\pmb{curl}(\pmb G) = 0$.